# Cocoa XML-RPC framework XMLRPCConnection methods

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xml-rpc

If anyone has any experience in this framework: https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc/, it would be best, but I will try to fill in where I can.

There's a connection manager class, that stores each connection in a hash table that uses a UUID as the key. The manager has a method that you can spawn a new connection with a request object. Here's the problem:

I can get the connection object, but I can't find a way to send another method request through the same connection. The only thing I saw was a class method that is public, otherwise I can't figure out how to send another request through the same connection. Do I need to keep making new connections in order to do this?

Here's the connection class: https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc/blob/master/XMLRPCConnection.h

Here's the manager class: https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc/blob/master/XMLRPCConnectionManager.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to get this connection again. It's just a one-use connection. I asked the author to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this Framework, but upon looking at it briefly I came up with this. Theres a method,

```
- (XMLRPCConnection *)connectionForIdentifier: (NSString *)identifier;
```

If you can store reference to the identifier for the request you make the first time, then you can retrieve the same Connection with provided identifer, and not create a new one.

Comment: I saw the same thing, But if you look at XMLRPC Connection, there is no method on that object that you can use to send another request through that connection. There IS a class method, but it doesn't seem to make sense to me why it's there but I didn't study that method for a long time.